# Hibernate many-to-many with map collection

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many

I have two tables "Station" and "Route". Route can contain many stations and every station can be a part of the different routes. The logical solution is to create a table with 'station_id' and 'route_id' fields and there are lot of examples on the internet how to organize all of this stuff with hibernate. But I need to store the order number of each station in the route, so 3rd table populates with one more field 'orderNumber', so we get the following structure:

### RouteStations

- route_id
- station_id
- orderNumber

I created the next beans:

```
public class Station extends Identifier{

    private String title;
}

public class Route extends Identifier{
    private String name;
    private Map<Integer, Station> stations = new HashMap<Integer, Station>();
}
```

So I use the HashMap collection to store the orderNumber variable.
Help me please to map such type of relation using hibernate or propose the other solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hummm,

> I need to store **the order number** of each station in the route

Why do you do not use a List instead. You just have to create a linked table

```
@Entity
public class Route {

    private Integer id;

    private List<RouteAndStation> stationList = new ArrayList<RouteAndStation>();

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="route")
    @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
    public List<RouteAndStation> getStationList() {
        return this.stationList;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Station> getStationByOrderNumber() {
        Collections.sort(this.stationList, new Comparator<RouteAndStation>() {
            public int compare(RouteAndStation o1, RouteAndStation o2) {
                return o1.getOrderNumber().compareTo(o2.getOrderNumber());
            }
        });

        List<Station> sList = new ArrayList();
        for(RouteAndStation routeAndStation: this.stationList)
            sList.add(routeAndStation.getStation());

        return sList;
    }

    public void addStation(Station station) {
        RouteAndStation routeAndStation = new RouteAndStation();

        routeAndStation.addStation(this, station, getStationList().size());

        getStationList().add(routeAndStation);
    }

}
```

And Station

```
@Entity
public class Station {

    private Integer id;

    private List<RouteAndStation> routeList = new ArrayList<RouteAndStation>();

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
       return this.id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="station")
    // DO YOU NEDD CASCADE ???
    @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
    public List<RouteAndStation> getRouteList() {
        return this.routeList;
    }


}
```

RouteAndStation is implemented as follows

```
@Entity
public class RouteAndStation {

    private Route route;
    private Station station;

    private Integer stationNumber;

    private RouteAndStationId routeAndStationId;

    @EmbeddedId
    public RouteAndStationId getRouteAndStationId() {
        return this.routeAndStationId;
    }

    public void addStation(Route route, Station station, Integer stationNumber) {
        this.route = route;
        this.station = station;

        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;

        setRouteAndStationId(new RouteAndStationId(route.getId(), station.getId));
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ROUTE_ID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    public Route getRoute() {
        return this.route;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="STATION_ID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    public Station getStation() {
        return this.station;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class RouteAndStationId implements Serializable {

        private Integer routeId;
        private Integer stationId;

        // required no-arg constructor
        public RouteAndStationId() {}

        public RouteAndStationId(Integer routeId, Integer stationId) {
            this.routeId = routeId;
            this.stationId = stationId;
        }

        @Column(name="ROUTE_ID")
        public Integer getRouteId {
            return this.routeId;
        }

        @Column(name="STATION_ID")
        public Integer getStationId {
            return this.stationId;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o == null)
                return false;

            if(!(o instanceof RouteAndStationId))
                return false;

            RouteAndStationId other = (RouteAndStationId) o;
            if(!(getRouteId().equals(other.getRouteId())))
                return false;

            if(!(getStationId().equals(other.getStationId())))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

I hope it can be useful to you

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to store extra information in the RouteStation table it might be better to promote it to a full class. You will end up with something like this:

```
 public class Station extends Identifier{
    private String title;
    private List<RouteStation> routes;
 }

 public class Route extends Identifier{
    private String name;
    private List<RouteStation> stations;
 }

 Public class RouteStation{
     private Station station;
     private Route route;
     private Integer orderNumber;
 }
```

You can then make the mapping so that the RouteStation class owns the relationships between Route and Station. You now have to create two individual one-to-many bi directional mappings.

Comment: Yeah, it's obvious solution, but relational model from database reflects on the objects here whereas objects have to use an object model as I think. Must be a way to organize many-to-many like I answered above but I'm confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. But I think there shouldn't be an 'RouteAndStation' entity. I tried to map my 'Route' class on two tables in the database like this:

```
<class name="Route" table="Route">

    <id name="id" column="routeId" type="long" unsaved-value="-1">
            <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="name" />

    <map name="stations" table="RouteStations" cascade="all">
            <key column="routeId" />
            <map-key-many-to-many column="stationId" class="Station"/>
            <element column="orderNumber" type="int"/>
        </map>

</class>
```

But when I save the Route object only one query performs by hibernate:

```
insert into Route (name) values (?)
```

Comment: @j3raks Just an advice: do you want to use a Map as a way to avoid a joined class, right ??? But what happens if you need to add a new property on linked table ??? You need to change all your model. Think about it. Your app does not need to know about your joined class. If you see, encapsulation is used to hide your joined class. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I see encapsulation. I'll use your solution. Many thanks.